# cross validation using the SPSE in R

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation

We have implemented an cross validation method in R. But we are not sure whether the error that it puts out is correct. We want it to give us the sum of predicted squared errors (SPSE), but in our simulation we have an completely wrong mean error. (The simulation code is not included, because its quite messy. If someone wants to help us a really big time, we can include it afterwards). In our simulation we predict the target value, and then run the cross validation for each model and make see what model fits the calculated theoretical SPSE. But it does not fit at all, so we are not sure anymore, if our code for the cross validation is correct. If someone could help us we would be saved.

```
partition<-function(data, d){
  #Randomly shuffle the data
  yourData<-data[sample(nrow(data)),]

  #Create 10 equally size folds
  folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(yourData)),breaks=d,labels=FALSE)
  return(list("data" = yourData, "folds" = folds))
}

errorfun<-function(testData, prediction, count){
  return(sum((testData[,6] - unname(prediction)))^2)
}


cv<-function(data, folds, model, d){
  err <- 0
  #Perform 10 fold cross validation
  for(i in 1:d){
    #Segement your data by fold using the which() function 
    testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
    testData <- data[testIndexes, ]
    trainData <- data[-testIndexes, ]
    lm.training <- lm(model, data=trainData)

    prediction <- predict.lm(lm.training, newdata = testData)
    count <- nrow(testData)
    err <- err + errorfun(testData = testData, prediction = prediction, count)
  }
  return(err)
}
```

(I tried it in math.stackexchange, but was redirected here :))

Answer (score 0):

You need to square it before summing, otherwise it doesn't make sense.. And you should not sum up the cross-validation errors, they should be keep separate. Something like below should be ok, I simplified some of the code:

```
errorfun<-function(testData, prediction){
  return(sum((testData[,6] - prediction)^2))
}

cv<-function(data, model, d){

  idx = split(sample(nrow(data)),1:nrow(data) %% d)

  err = vector("numeric",d)

  for(i in 1:d){

    testData <- data[idx[[i]], ]
    trainData <- data[-idx[[i]], ]
    lm.training <- lm(model, data=trainData)

    prediction <- predict.lm(lm.training, newdata = testData)
    err[[i]] <- errorfun(testData,prediction)
  }
  return(err)
}

library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
dat = BostonHousing[,c(1:5,ncol(BostonHousing))]

set.seed(111)
cv(dat,as.formula("medv ~ ."),5)
[1] 6079.635 4707.216 6433.543 6145.103 6103.232
```